# IIS not using SSL certificates

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, iis-7

My setup:

- Azure Vm : Windows server 2008
- IIS 7.5

I have purchased a domain from godaddy and pointed it to the Azure VPS. Initially the website was running on IIS using http on port 80. I have purchased SSL from godaddy using CSR and installed them as following

1. Intermediate certificate using MMC
2. Server certificate using IIS

Then I bind the certificate with my website using https on port 443, but when I visited my website it's not loading up it on https and gives an error "**This site can't be reached**. I have also checked **secure world wide web and https is checked in my firewall settings**.

Comment: Have you enabled at Azure portal access to port 443? Meanwhile, you should also review your certificate installation if the certificate disappears, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Comment: @LexLi Azure portal access to 443 is enabled and certificate ins't disappearing from IIS.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for comment, Azure endpoint for port 443 isn't added. After adding endpoint for 443 working perfectly. :)

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by

1. Goto your Azure VM
2. In Azure VM -> Find Endpoints
3. Click on Add endpoint
4. Add endpoint for you port (in my case 443) and give it a name ( e.g https)
5. Save
6. Done

Comment: appreciate that you have added the answer, after you have found it